# Different document root for https version of site - cloudflare ssl

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I'm having a site just issued a free ssl certificate. Which was installed automatically after changing dns. The site works fine for http version domain but when I try https domain it shows a cpanel login page.

Please suggest something as I cannot find any option for https document root in settings of cpanel. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's difficult to say without more information (like your domain). It could be that you're not sending SNI. Would be a good idea to file a ticket with support.cloudflare.com so they can provide account specific help.

Comment: anyways I've installed the certificate manually and it works now!